# Why can't I instantiate operator<<(ostream&, vector<T>&) with T=vector<int>?

Tags: c++, templates, iostream

In thinking about [C++ iterator question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347134/c-iterator-question), I wrote this sample program:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm> 

template <class T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&os, const std::vector<T>& v) 
{ 
    os<<"(";
    std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<T>(os, ", "));
    return os<<")";
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v(3);
    std::vector<std::vector<int> > vv(3, v);
    std::cout << v << "\n"; // this line works
    std::cout << vv << "\n"; // this line produces error
}
```

I compile this program with gcc and get the typical 100 lines of errors. The relevant part, I believe, is:

> it.cc:19:   instantiated from here
>
> /usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stream_iterator.h:191: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ in ‘*((std::ostream_iterator >, char, std::char_traits >*)this)->std::ostream_iterator >, char, std::char_traits >::_M_stream << __value’

Why does this fail? In my templated `operator<<`, I try to specify that *any vector*, regardless of type, is printable. So why doesn't `std::vector<std::vector<>>` print?

**EDIT**: Using the following code in the template function makes it work

```
#if 0
    std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<T>(os, ", "));
#else
    for(typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator it = v.begin();
        it != v.end();
        it++) {
        os<<(*it)<<", ";
    }
#endif
```

Comment: Doesn't work in Intel C++ either.

Comment: Does it work if you replace `std::copy` with a manual loop?

Comment: I don't know the exact reason this happens(I think it has something to do with ADL).  But I've found that if I put the function into the std namespace, it fixes the problem.  Though I'm not sure if that's a good idea or not.

Comment: Thanks @larsmans. It fails in `clang++`, also. I assume that the problem is in my program, not the compiler.

Comment: Thanks, @Benjamin. Putting anything in `std::` *seems* like a bad idea.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Two words:  name lookup.

Here is a simplified example of what you are trying to do, without any Standard Library headers required:

```
template <typename T> void f(T) { }

namespace ns {
    class C { };

    void f(int) { }

    void test() { f(C()); } // doesn't work :'(
}

int main() {
    f(ns::C());             // works!  :-D
}
```

In this example, in `main()`, the only `f` that is found during normal name lookup is the function template in the global namespace, and it matches, so `main` uses it (`ns::f` is also found during argument-dependent lookup, but it isn't a match so the global `f` is still selected during overload resolution).

In `test`, however, the `ns::f(int)` overload is found and name lookup stops.  Namespaces are searched outwards, so `ns` is searched first, then the global namespace, but name lookup stops once a name is found, so once `ns::f(int)` is found, name lookup stops.  Argument-dependent lookup also takes place and also finds `ns::f(int)`, since `C` is in namespace `ns`, then ADL stops searching.

The same is true in your example:  in `main()`, the `operator<<` overload is found, but inside of the `std::ostream_iterator`, which is in the `std` namespace, other `<<` overloads are found, and so your overload is not found.

Your `operator<<` overload would need to be in the `std` namespace for it to work, but unfortunately you aren't allowed to add names to the `std` namespace.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation. Reducing a template problem by eliminating STL is a good technique for explaining this.

Comment: @Rob: you might want to read about Argument Dependent Lookup. For your information... I simply added those overloads within the `std` namespace. It's forbidden, daemons might fly out of my nose... but it works for me (and I'll have to check it out when a new compiler is released).

Comment: Thanks, @Matthieu. I was just reading http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup as you were typing that comment!

Comment: "In this example, in main(), the only f available is the function template in the global namespace". This is not true. ADL will find `f(int)` too, which however cannot accept the argument. The call `f(C())` fails because it only finds `f(int)`, and the template is not considered by ADL and is in an enclosing namespace. "note that ns::f would be found during argument-dependent lookup if no f was found during normal name lookup" that rule only applies if normal lookup finds a class member function or a local function declaration that is not a using declaration. It doesn't apply here.

Comment: @Johannes: Thanks for the correction. Updated with corrections; let me know if I've still screwed it up.

Comment: @James yeah now it looks correct. I've added some explanation of my own as a new answer to clear matters up.

Comment: Hope you don't mind me chiming in and trolling the answers like that -.-

Comment: @Johannes: I certainly don't :)

Comment: @Johannes:  No, I don't mind at all.  Please continue :-).  I contribute here so that I can hopefully understand C++ better and so that I can learn to explain the language concisely and correctly.  Your comments and answers are absolutely invaluable and are greatly appreciated (especially for questions like this; I am still very noobish when it comes to name resolution, ADL, and overload resolution).

Comment: Actually providing implementation inside the std namespace is common practice and not at all discouraged. Examples include custom specializations of `std::less` for your own types.

Comment: @jupp0r C++14 §17.6.4.2.1[namespace.std]/1:  "The behavior of a C++ program is undefined if it adds declarations or definitions to namespace std or to a namespace within namespace std unless otherwise specified. A program may add a template specialization for any standard library template to namespace std only if the declaration depends on a user-defined type and the specialization meets the standard library requirements for the original template and is not explicitly prohibited."

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I was not aware of the restriction to specializations to user-defined types, but it makes perfect sense thinking about it.

Answer (score 8):

Lookup in the instantiation context of a function template only uses ADL. No unqualified lookup. Therefor, you need to rely on ADL. But the ADL lookup for `vector<int>` does not include the global namespace, hence your `operator<<` is not found. Try this, which should work fine:

```
struct A { 
  operator int() const { return 0; }
};

template <class T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&os, const std::vector<T>& v) 
{ 
    os<<"(";
    std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<T>(os, ", "));
    return os<<")";
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<A> v(3);
    std::vector< std::vector<A> > vv(3, v);
    std::cout << vv << "\n"; // should work fine
}
```

This works because the global namespace is associated with the ADL lookup set for `std::vector<A>` (because `A` is a template argument), therefor finding the globally declared template when instantiating the respective member functions of `std::ostream_iterator<>`, which will use your `operator<<` for `T` being `A`, which then in turn will use `operator<<(int)` of `std::ostream`.

Comment: Cool. To restate your answer slightly, using my original `operator<<` template, I can `cout<<vector<vector<MyClass> >()`, even though I cannot `cout<<vector<vector<POD> >()`, for the ADL reasons you stated. (Assuming that I can `cout<<MyClass()`, of course). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think since `std::copy` is defined in different namespace, and the generated code from the function template `std::copy` and `ostream_iterator` class template, is unable to find the `operator<<` defined by you which exists in different namespace.

To solve this problem you've to define `operator<<` in `std` namespace as shown below:

```
namespace std //note the namespace
{
   template <class T>
   std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&os, const std::vector<T>& v) 
   { 
     os<<"(";
      std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<T>(os, ", "));
      return os<<")"; 
   }
}
```

Working code at ideone : http://ideone.com/sFenn

However, I cannot say how good the idea of implementing it is in `std` namespace!

---

Alternatively, you can define `operator<<` as (**without using `std::copy`**):

```
template <class T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&os, const std::vector<T>& v) 
{ 
   typedef typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator const_iterator;
   os<<"(";
   for (const_iterator it = v.begin() ; it != v.end() ; ++it )
       os << *it << ", ";
   return os<<")"; 
}
```

Working code : http://ideone.com/FXWlP

Comment: Overloads cannot be added to the `std` namespace.

Comment: Thanks! Great minds think alike. See @FredOverflow's comment on my question, and my subsequent edit.

Comment: @James: I was about to have that doubt. Anyway, I added one more line to my answer. BTW, what do you think overloads cannot be added to the `std` namespace?

Comment: Undefined Behavior.  17.4.3.1 "It is undefined for a C++ program to add declarations or definitions to namespace `std` or namespaces within namespace `std` unless otherwise specified."

Comment: Because the authors of Standard Library implementations need to be able to know that when they make a qualified call to a function, it calls the function they expect to be called, not some user-added overload.