# Print vector of vectors to ostream

Tags: c++, vector, ostream

Please consider the following code. I'm trying to output a vector of vectors to an ostream.

```
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

template<typename T>
std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &os, const std::vector<T> &v) {
    using namespace std;
    copy(v.begin(), v.end(), ostream_iterator<T>(os, "\n"));
    return os;
}

int main() {
    using namespace std;
    vector<string> v1;
    cout << v1;
    vector<vector<string> > v2;
    cout << v2;
    return 0;
}
```

The statement where I output a vector of strings works. The one where I output a vector of vectors of strings doesn't. I'm using g++ 4.7.0. I've tried w/ & w/o the -std=c++11 flag. In C++11 mode, it gives me this line in the half-page of errors.

```
error: cannot bind 'std::ostream_iterator<std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >, char, std::char_traits<char> >::ostream_type {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}' lvalue to 'std::basic_ostream<char>&&'
```

I don't think I understand what it means. Could someone explain to me? I more or less know what an rvalue reference is, but I don't see why `std::basic_ostream<char>` wouldn't bind to `std::basic_ostream<char>&&`. Maybe I don't know it well enough. And is there a better way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: think about it, in `vector<vector<string > >` case, "\n" have to be castable to `vector<string >`. Of cause it won't work

Comment: @J-16SDiZ: What are you talking about? No it doesn't.

Comment: @J-16SDiZ: No. That is simply wrong.

Comment: Very nearly **exact** duplicate of [Why can't I instantiate operator<<(ostream&, vector<T>&) with T=vector<int>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5355081/why-cant-i-instantiate-operatorostream-vectort-with-t-vectorint)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error you're getting is a bit misleading.  When I tried to compile your program I had to dig into the template vomit quite a bit, and I ended up with what I thought was going on:

```
error: no match for 'operator<<' in '*((std::ostream_iterator<std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >, char, std::char_traits<char> >*)this)->std::ostream_iterator<std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >, char, std::char_traits<char> >::_M_stream << __value'
```

Basically, when you called the copy algorithm, it used the output iterator, which used the << operator from within namespace std.  Once there, lookup dictates that it try to find an overload for the template vector<> in the std namespace (because that's where IT resides).

So what you need to do is declare your stream operator for the vector template in namespace std.  Surround your code with `namespace std {}` and see what happens...

It should be noted that what you're doing is basically modifying std::vector<> and adding behavior to it that wasn't there before.  Doing this is non-standard, undefined, and can easily get in your way.  You might consider other options.

---

I was wrong about this being a koenig lookup thing.  It's not, the issue is name hiding similar to what occurs in classes here you declare an overload of something in a base (not an override).

The standard namespace declares several '<<' operators.  These are basically functions named `operator <<`.  In essence what you have is this:

```
void fun(int);

namespace Test {

  void fun() { fun(3); }

}

int main() {
    Test::fun();
}
```

Note that you can use `fun(int)` from the global namespace or any namespace that does not have any function named `fun` in it.  You can't use it from the `Test` namespace.

This is why your use of operator << declared globally works fine from the global namespace but not from within the `std` namespace.  The `std` namespace already has things named the same thing as the overload you're trying to provide and so that overload is hidden from all things within `std`.  If you could put a using declaration there things would be different.

Comment: Putting things in the std namespace not permitted by the standard is it?  Regardless, I highly doubt it would actually cause a problem in any real implementation, and it seems to work for me.

Comment: Yup, that worked! Thanks!

I don't fully understand, though. If it can find the overload for vector<string>, where T is string, in the global namespace, how come it can't find the overload in the 2nd level of the 2-level lookup? Is the output iterator code in the std namespace written to look for std::operator <<?

I also agree with Benjamin's concern - is this something that's encouraged?

Comment: It's undefined behavior, but you gotta do what you gotta do.  If it was defined already it would work already.

Comment: @Ashley - has to do with the scope of the call as well.  Name lookup is kind of a complicated mess, especially wrt templates.  Have a read about koenig lookup and other name lookup rules.

Comment: @CrazyEddie, tks. Anyone else, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup) has a pretty good explanation. You'll see that the global namespace isn't searched in this case.

Answer (score 4):

You need this utility library:

- [Pretty-print C++ STL containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850473/pretty-print-c-stl-containers)

---

If you want to do this yourself (so as to teach yourself), then you need to define two overloads as:

- For `std::vector<T>`:

  ```
  template<typename T>
  std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &os, const std::vector<T> &v) {
     using namespace std;
     copy(v.begin(), v.end(), ostream_iterator<T>(os, "\n"));
     return os;
  }
  ```
- For `std::vector<std::vector<T>>`:

  ```
  template<typename T>
  std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &os, const std::vector<std::vector<T>> &v) {
     using namespace std;

     //NOTE: for some reason std::copy doesn't work here, so I use manual loop
     //copy(v.begin(), v.end(), ostream_iterator<std::vector<T>>(os, "\n"));

     for(size_t i = 0 ; i < v.size(); ++i)
          os << v[i] << "\n";
     return os;
  }
  ```

If you have these overloads, then they together will handle these cases recursively:

```
std::vector<int>  v;
std::vector<std::vector<int>>  vv;
std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>>  vvv;
std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>>>  vvvv;

std::cout << v << std::endl; //ok
std::cout << vv << std::endl; //ok
std::cout << vvv << std::endl; //ok
std::cout << vvvv << std::endl; //ok
```

Comment: Is there something else you're doing to get this to work?  Because it doesn't work for me. http://ideone.com/A2d67

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: I don't see any reason why it shouldn't work. Maybe a compiler bug? Anyway, the manual loop works fine.

Comment: The other version didn't work, because the `ostream_iterator` is in the `std` namespace, as is `vector`.  As such, ADL fails to find the  `operator <<` template you've defined, and it fails to compile.

Comment: @DaveS: I am not convinced. Why does the manual loop work then? How does it find `operator<<` template I've defined?

Comment: @Nawaz: My guess is that it's because your `operator<<` is in the global namespace, so it's searched as well.  In fact, if you change the OP's original code to use a manual loop (vs. copy/iterator), it works without any further modifications ( http://ideone.com/rVBY2 ).  Hmm... it could be a bug in the late binding for the template

Comment: @Nawaz - if you avoid `std::copy` in the first function, you don't need the second.

Comment: I've spent some time looking at the standard and doing some tests.  My answer now reflects my findings and explains why one works and the other does not.  Actually has nothing to do with ADL.