# BOOST unittest override operator<<

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost

To test two `std::pair`

```
BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(std::make_pair(0.0,0.0), std::make_pair(1.0,1.0));
```

I overloads the `operator<<` for `std::pair`

```
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, const std::pair<double,double>& t)
{
  return os << "( " << t.first << ", " << t.second << ")"; 
}
```

with following error

```
error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

What is wrong?

Comment: You probably mean "overload", not "override".

Comment: @Jesse Good, i test your solution with the namespace arround and it works (but I don't know why)

Comment: @Behelke: I undeleted my answer since it worked. Trying to figure out what exactly is going on though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open up the `std namespace` so ADL can find it.

```
namespace std
{
ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, const pair<double,double>& t)
{
  return os << "( " << t.first << ", " << t.second << ")"; 
}
}
```

Ok, I figured it out. Name lookup **stops** when it finds the name it is looking for in the current namespace, which is why it cannot find your `operator<<` in global scope, since it found `operator<<` already in `namespace boost` because boost declares `operator<<`.

I recommend reading [Why can't I instantiate operator<<(ostream&, vector&) with T=vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5355081/why-cant-i-instantiate-operatorostream-vectort-with-t-vectorint) which has a good explanation.

Comment: Is it needed to write `std::ostream` and `std::pair`? Wouldn't it mean `std::std::pair` ?

Comment: it's not needed to write std::ostream

Comment: While this is working it is actually undefined behaviour (at least for C++14 and up) as one shall not add functions to std namespace