# C++ resolving ostream operator<< overload for STL containers with ostream_iterator

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

I've written an overload of ostream operator<< for std::vector. It's based on a solution found somwhere here, in the depths of stackoverflow:

```cpp
template <typename T, typename AllocT>
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, const std::vector<T, AllocT>& v) {
    if (!v.empty()) {
        out << "[";
        std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<T>(out, ", "));
        out << "\b\b]";
    }
    return out;
}
```

Everything seems to work perfectly fine with simple types:

```cpp
auto vt = std::vector<int>({ 1, 2, 4 });
std::cout << vt;

>> [1, 2, 4]
```

However, whenever I try to make this recursive:

```cpp
auto vt = std::vector<std::vector<int>>({ {1, 2}, {3, 4} });
std::cout << vt;

>> error C2679: binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const _Ty' (or there is no acceptable conversion) 
            with
            [
                _Ty=std::vector<int,std::allocator<int>>
            ]
... while trying to match the argument list '(std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>, const _Ty)'...
... while compiling class template member function 'std::ostream_iterator<T,char,std::char_traits<char>>
   &std::ostream_iterator<T,char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator =(const _Ty &)'
            with
            [
                T=std::vector<int,std::allocator<int>>,
                _Ty=std::vector<int,std::allocator<int>>
            ]
```

It's quite strange, since the complier seem to be stuck on resolving overload for `operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>, const std::vector<int,std::allocator<int>>&)`, which (in theory) we should be able to produce.

As far as I understand, `std::ostream` is actually the same as `std::basic_ostream<char>`, so there should not be any problems here. Or maybe something's wrong with constness, though I also can't see the actual problem.

Comment: Also, this might be helpful/dupe: [Why can't I instantiate operator<<(ostream&, vector<T>&) with T=vector<int>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5355081/why-cant-i-instantiate-operatorostream-vectort-with-t-vectorint)